# Calculating $\mathbb{E}\left(\tfrac{XX^T}{\|AX\|^2}\right)$ for isotropic random vectors $X$

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices

$\newcommand{\EE}{\mathbb{E}}$
Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $X$ be an isotropic random vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. it holds that $\EE(XX^T) = I_n$.

How to calculate $$M = \EE\left(\tfrac{XX^T}{\|AX\|^2}\right)$$
and/or $$AMA^T = \EE\left(\tfrac{AXX^TA^T}{\|AX\|^2}\right) = \EE\left(\tfrac{AXX^TA^T}{X^TA^TAX}\right)?$$

For $X$ being a (scaled) random unit coordinate vector $\sqrt{n}e_k$ where $k$ is uniformly distributed on $\{1,\dots,n\}$ that's simple to do, but would be interested in other isotropic distributions, e.g.

- normally distributed $X$,
- Rademacher vectors $X$ ($X_i = \pm 1$ with equal probability and independently)
- $X$ uniformly
  distributed on the sphere of radius $\sqrt{n}$.

I would also be happy with (bounds on) the smallest and largest eigenvalues of $M$ and $AMA^T$.

Comment: Just a quick observation: Since the term under the expectation is $0$-homogeneous, the matrix $M$ will only depend on the marginal distribution of $X$ on the the sphere $S^{n-1}$.

Comment: Yes, this is true! If $m\geq n$  one can derive that the smallest eigenvalue of $M$ is larger that $1/(d\sigma_{\max}(A)^2)$ and the largest is smaller that $1/(d\sigma_{\min}(A)^2)$ (where $\sigma$ stands for singular values), but these bounds seems quite loose for all distributions I checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $X\sim N(0,I)$, writing $A^TA=\sum_i L_i u_i u_i^T$, since $sign(u_i^TX)$ and $sign(u_k^TX)$ are independent and mean-zero, $u_i^TMu_k=0$ if $i\le k$ because the denominator
$\|AX\|^2=\sum_i L_i Z_i^2$ is independent of the signs, where $Z_i=u_i^TX$ are iid $N(0,1)$.
This shows that $M$ is diagonalizable in the same basis as $A^TA$. It remains to compute the diagonal terms in the basis $(u_i)$, and
$$
u_i^TMu_i = E\Big[ \frac{Z_i^2}{\sum_k L_k Z_k^2}\Big]
$$
where $Z_i=u_i^TX$ are iid $N(0,1)$. Unfortunately, I do not think explicit expressions are available for general $L_k$ for the expectation in the right-hand side.